# setTimeout from within an event handler not appearing to fire

Tags: javascript, events

Am aware that not all setTimout tasks put on the queue are actually fired (thanks a post by bobnice on this). Yet I can't understand why it would not be reached in this case :

I add the following event handler to an anchor link (via `addEventListener( 'click', ...` ) to experiment with so-called "in-flight event modification" :

```
var f = function(e) {  
    e.preventDefault(); 
    e.stopPropagation(); // capture first event
    e2 = new MouseEvent("click",{metaKey:true}); // create second event where we hold meta
    e.target.removeEventListener('click', f, false); // remove this handler so no stackoverflow
    e.target.dispatchEvent(e2); // dispatch second event, a "modified" first event.
};
```

Works fine.

However, an earlier version had this :

```
setTimeout( 0, function () {
    e.target.dispatchEvent(e2); // dispatch second event, a "modified" first event.
});
```

From within the handler (as a debugging patch to try to avoid stackoverflow when I couldn't get the removeEventListener to work -- I had neglected to assign my function `f` to a variable).

Why would this setTimeout not execute? In  my handful of tests, it never once executed the dispatching of the second event from within the listener for the first event.

Clearly, the setTimeout puts the execution context of`dispatchEvent` outside of the stack frame for the function `f`, as `f` returns before `dispatchEvent` fires.

Or, rather, *doesn't* fire.

I would like to understand exactly why it didn't fire in this previous version of the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The timeout delay for [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) should be the second argument, not the first! That's why it didn't fire.

Comment: I always mix that up!

Comment: @Cris `e` is also not declared in setTimeout.

Comment: @ps2goat wouldn't it be closed over from inside the anonymous function in the setTimeout since the setTimout is within `f`?

Comment: @ps2goat no it didn't. It said "from within the handler" which is not clear without reading the words. If you read the words it is clear.